# Removing Values From a Map in a loop

Tags: java, hashmap

I am trying to compare two maps and remove values from one map that are contained in a second map. Here is the code:

```
    HashMap<String, String> firstMap = new HashMap<>();
    HashMap<String, String> secondMap = new HashMap<>();

    firstMap.put("keyOne", "valueOne");
    firstMap.put("keyTwo", "valueTwo");
    firstMap.put("THIS KEY WILL BE REMOVED", "valueThree");

    System.out.println("\nMAP ONE\n" + firstMap +  "\n");

    secondMap.put("keyOne", "valueOne");
    secondMap.put("keyTwo", "valueTwo");

    System.out.println("\nMAP TWO\n" + secondMap +  "\n");

    Iterator<String> firstMapIterator = firstMap.keySet().iterator();

    if(!firstMap.equals(secondMap)){

            firstMapIterator.next();

            for(String key : firstMap.keySet()){

                if(firstMap.containsKey(key) && !secondMap.containsKey(key)){
                    firstMapIterator.remove();
                    break;
                }
            }
    }
    System.out.println("\nMAP ONE MATCHING MAP TWO?\n" + firstMap +  "\n");
```

Now, the code does remove an element from the map but not the one I was expecting. As you can see in the code in `firstMap` I have entered a third key of which is the one I expect to be removed. However, this is the final contents of `firstMap`I seem to be getting.

```
{keyOne=valueOne, THIS KEY WILL BE REMOVED=valueThree}
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Edit: The goal of this code is to: 
 - Compare two maps
 - Increment through each key
 - Remove key from firstMap if it is not found in secondMap

Comment: Please **edit** your question to clarify that you want to remove  values from one map that are **not** contained in a second map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using the iterator correctly. You only advance the iterator once (`firstMapIterator.next()`), so the first key obtained by the iterator will be the one removed from the Map, regardless of the current `key` in the `for(String key : firstMap.keySet())` loop.

You don't need the `for` loop:

```
Iterator<String> firstMapIterator = firstMap.keySet().iterator();
while (firstMapIterator.hasNext()) {
    if(!secondMap.containsKey(firstMapIterator.next())) {
        firstMapIterator.remove();
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: So I moved `firstMapIterator.next()` inside the for loop and now it seems to be working correctly. Thank you - ah just seen edit will read again

Comment: @ribenalight123 As I said, you don't need the for loop. Using both an explicit iterator and an enhanced for loop is pointless.

Comment: Thank you for the help. Your code example is great thank you

Comment: Do you need the `break;`? What if there are two entries that need to be removed?

Comment: @DodgyCodeException The OP's code had a break, so I assumed the OP only wanted to remove one key. I may be wrong.

Comment: Also, do you really need the `if` check? The `equals` iterates through the map in a similar way that you subsequently iterate, so it's duplicating effort.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in just one line:

```
    HashMap<String, String> firstMap = new HashMap<>();
    HashMap<String, String> secondMap = new HashMap<>();

    firstMap.put("keyOne", "valueOne");
    firstMap.put("keyTwo", "valueTwo");
    firstMap.put("THIS KEY WILL BE REMOVED", "valueThree");

    System.out.println("\nMAP ONE\n" + firstMap + "\n");

    secondMap.put("keyOne", "valueOne");
    secondMap.put("keyTwo", "valueTwo");

    System.out.println("\nMAP TWO\n" + secondMap + "\n");

    // Remove everything from firstMap that is in secondMap.
    firstMap.keySet().removeAll(secondMap.keySet());

    System.out.println("\nMAP ONE MATCHING MAP TWO?\n" + firstMap + "\n");
```

See the JavaDoc for [Map.keySet()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#keySet()):

> Returns a Set view of the keys contained in this map. The set is backed by the map, so changes to the map are reflected in the set, **and vice-versa**. ... The set supports element removal, which removes the corresponding mapping from the map, via the Iterator.remove, Set.remove, removeAll, retainAll, and clear operations....

Comment: That is a good sample thank you but not achieving what I wanted, sorry for lack of clarity in original post. I was removing all elements **not** present in the map. Not all elements that are present

Comment: @ribenalight123 Then you can use `retainAll` instead of `removeAll`.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to iterate over the maps.

You can simply do

```
firstMap.keySet().removeAll(secondMap.keySet());
```

This will remove all keys from the first map that are present in the second map.

Also, you can remove all keys in the first map that are **not** in the second map using:

```
firstMap.keySet().retainAll(secondMap.keySet());
```

Comment: Think you were beaten to it ;)

Answer (score 1):

As others have already said, you can do it in one single line:

```
firstMap.keySet().removeAll(secondMap.keySet());
```

Another way would be by using the [`Collection.removeIf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-) method:

```
firstMap.keySet().removeIf(k -> secondMap.containsKey(k));
```

The above can be rewritten as follows:

```
firstMap.keySet().removeIf(secondMap::containsKey);
```

Answer (score 0):

check your `firstMapIterator.next();`  add into for loop

```
 HashMap<String, String> firstMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
                HashMap<String, String> secondMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

                firstMap.put("keyOne", "valueOne");
                firstMap.put("keyTwo", "valueTwo");
                firstMap.put("THIS KEY WILL BE REMOVED", "valueThree");

                System.out.println("\nMAP ONE\n" + firstMap +  "\n");

                secondMap.put("keyOne", "valueOne");
                secondMap.put("keyTwo", "valueTwo");

                System.out.println("\nMAP TWO\n" + secondMap +  "\n");

                Iterator<String> firstMapIterator = firstMap.keySet().iterator();

                if(!firstMap.equals(secondMap)){



                    for(String key : firstMap.keySet()){
                        firstMapIterator.next();//add here in for loop
                        if(firstMap.containsKey(key) && !secondMap.containsKey(key)){
                            firstMapIterator.remove();
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("\nMAP ONE MATCHING MAP TWO?\n" + firstMap +  "\n");
```